# How to render HTML as rendered HTML in jQuery.tmpl()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I can't assign HTML properly using jQuery.tmpl(). If i pass value of something as html tag it is rendered as  **as it is** instead of HTML tags rendered on page

```
<div id="window">
    <script id="lines" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <div id="${id}" class="line ${type}"><span>${name}</span>: ${body}</div>
    </script>
</div>



var line = {
            name: 'John',
            body: '<strong>hello</strong>
        };
        $('#lines').tmpl(line).appendTo('#window');
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can wrap the template variable with `{{html body}}` to override the default encoding behavior.

Comment: you mean like so? <div id="${id}" class="line ${type}"><span>${name}</span>: ${{html body}}</div>

Comment: without the dollar sign, just {{html body}}. here's a jsfiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/EW2Ca/

Comment: cheers, one more question. Can i put js code behind all template logic in separate file?

Comment: if you mean the `var line...;` and the `$('#lines').tmpl(..)...;` then yes :)

Comment: its work THX  thx     for google: jquery tmpl variable as with html tags

Comment: @eugeneK it does not metter where do you put the js :)

Answer (score 0):

In my Laravel Blade project, It's working only like the below syntax. `@{{html body}}`.

```
<div id="${id}" class="line ${type}">
    <span>${name}</span>: @{{html body}}
</div>
```

And we can add a method(HTML DOM return method) also here. like:

```
function getBody () {
   return '<b>hello</b>';
}

<div id="${id}" class="line ${type}">
    <span>${name}</span>: @{{html getBody()}}
</div>
```