# Cant build Html Control using jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-templates

I'm using jquery template for creating a html form and everything working perfect except I cant create the HTML controls , the form showing html controls as text  my code is given below

js

```
result[i].Control="<textarea id='"+result[i].Id+"'></textarea>";

$("#controlTemplate").tmpl(result).appendTo("#controlHolder");
```

template

```
<script id="controlTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
  <tr>
<td class="text-center">
     ${RowNumber}
</td>
<td>
     ${ControlLabel}
</td>
    <td class="control-td">
        ${Control}
    </td>
  </tr>

</script>
```

and my current out put is give below[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248962/how-to-render-html-as-rendered-html-in-jquery-tmpl

Comment: @monkeyinsight thank  u very much post u r comment as an answer